# Java Android error : current Month cannot be after end Month

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set up constraints for a Material Date Range Picker Dialog. The idea is to limit the range of the selectable dates from the current day to the same day one month later.

I have a method to build the constraints:

```
public CalendarConstraints.Builder setCalendarConstraints() {
    CalendarConstraints.Builder constraints = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();

    long min = setMinDate();
    long max = setMaxDate();

    constraints.setStart(min);
    constraints.setEnd(max);

    return constraints;
}
```

And the two following methods are used to get the minimum and maximum dates:

```
// Maximum date for the date picker is the current date + 1 month
public long setMaxDate() {
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate max;

    if (now.getMonthValue() == 12) {
        max = LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), 1, now.getDayOfMonth());
        max.plusYears(1);
    } else {
        max = LocalDate.of(now.getYear(), now.getMonth().plus(1), now.getDayOfMonth());
    }
    return max.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}
```

Everything was working when I was testing my app two weeks ago, so I think the problem comes from that we are now in December. I tried to add a year to the current year when we are in December, when it looks like it doesn't work as I have the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current Month cannot be after end Month

Comment: Could this be related to the bug listed here? https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1913

Comment: Tip: Your existing code will fail when the current moment happens to be around the stroke of midnight. Your two calls could inadvertently capture two different dates. Instead, capture the current date *before* your two calls, and pass the date as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

The method `LocalDate::plusYears()` doesn't work on the `LocalDate` itself. As the Javadoc says, it returns a new object, a copy of the original `LocalDate` Object but with with one year added.

So you'll need to write:

```
 max = max.plusYears(1);
```

By the way, you don't need to check for December.

```
LocalDate max = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1)
```

does the trick whether you're in December or not.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
LocalDate.now().plusMonths( 1 );
```

for max